# Reverse Engineering Saved File

Tags: delphi

I am trying to reverse engineer a file saved by a program written in Delphi. This file is generated by the `File -> Save As` menu item. How can I go about identifying the field names and byte offsets etc. of this file?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I go about identifying the field names and byte offsets etc.
>   of this file?

By reverse engineering the Delphi program, in particular the functionality that reads from and writes to those saved files.